Addon - Trouble using external packages
I am developing a python code that uses Blender for geometric manipulation and scene visualisation.
To do so, I am trying to create an add-on, named V01, that has the following structure
V01
  * __init__.py
  |- DATA
    |- DR
      * DR.xlsx
  |-src
    * __init__.py
    * definition.py
    |- DR
        * __init__.py
        * dr.py
    |- PARSER
      * __init__.py
      |- EXCEL
        * __init__.py
        * ExcelParser.py
        * ExcelParserDr.py

The top __init__.py file contains (I did not include the bl_info to avoid unnecessary clutter)
import sys
import pathlib
import importlib
import subprocess

# install necessary packages
packages = [
    {'name': 'numpy', 'importName': 'numpy', 'version': ''},
    {'name': 'scipy', 'importName': 'scipy', 'version': ''},
    {'name': 'pandas', 'importName': 'pandas', 'version': ''},
]

for package in packages:
    try:
        importlib.import_module(package['importName'])
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        if package['version']:
            subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', f"{package['name']} == {package['version']}", '--ignore-installed'])
        else:
            subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package['name'], '--ignore-installed'])

# Get the path to the addon directory
addon_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent
src_dir = addon_dir / 'src'

def register() -> None:
    print(f"Hi! (registering from {__file__})\n")

    if str(src_dir) not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, str(src_dir))

    if str(addon_dir) not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(1, str(addon_dir))

def unregister() -> None:
    print(f"See you! (unregistering from {__file__})")

    new_sys_path = [p for p in sys.path if ((p != str(src_dir)) and (p != str(addon_dir)))]
    sys.path = new_sys_path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    unregister()

The modules ExcelParser.py and ExcelParserDr.py include, amongst other things, the following
# ExcelParser.py module
import pathlib
import functools
import pandas

class ExcelParser:
    def __init__(self, FilePath):
        self._fpath = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: pathlib.Path(a)/b, FilePath)
        self._fdata: pandas.DataFrame = pandas.read_excel(self._fpath, sheet_name = None)

    @property
    def fpath(self):
        return self._fpath

    @fpath.setter
    def fpath(self, fpath):
        self._fpath = fpath

    @property
    def fdata(self) -> pandas.DataFrame:
        return self._fdata

    @fdata.setter
    def fdata(self, fdata: pandas.DataFrame) -> None:
        self._fdata: pandas.DataFrame = fdata

    def get_sheet_names(self):
        return list(self.fdata.keys())

    def get_column_data(self, sheet_name, col_name):
        return self.fdata[sheet_name][col_name].tolist()

and
# ExcelParserDr.py module
from src.PARSER.EXCEL.ExcelParser import ExcelParser
from src.definition import DATA_DR_DIR

class ExcelParserDr(ExcelParser):
    def __init__(self, FilePath):
        super().__init__(FilePath = FilePath)

    def get_m(self):
        return super().get_column_data(sheet_name = "MASS", col_name = "Mass [kg]")

When I try to run the file dr.py as a script in Blender, I get the following error
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

If I remove the type annotations in ExcelParser.py, I then get the error
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_excel'

I added the pandas package directly to the Blender lib folder, located at
C:\......\DESKTOP\SOFTWARE\BLENDER\4_1\4.1\python\lib

but my add-on is still not running. How can I make my code work?
EDIT
definition.py reads
import pathlib

current_file = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve()
ROOT_DIR = current_file.parent.parent
DATA_DR_DIR = ROOT_DIR / 'DATA' / 'DR'

and dr.py reads
import numpy as np
import bpy
from src.definition import DATA_DR_DIR
from src.PARSER.EXCEL.ExcelParserDr import ExcelParserDr

class Dr:
    def __init__(self, drDataFilepath = None):
        _data = ExcelParserDr(FilePath = drDataFilepath)
        self._m: float = _data.get_m()[0]

    @property
    def mass(self):
        return self._m

    @mass.setter
    def mass(self, m):
        self._m: float = m


d: Dr = Dr(drDataFilepath = [DATA_DR_DIR, "DR.xlsx"])

The file DR.xlsx is like this


You want to put required external libraries into a folder in your Configuration folder for whatever version you're using. Which can be found in C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\{version_number}. Then inside that folder you go to scripts\addons and if there isn't a modules folder in there then create one and put your installed external libraries there. More info about the path structure here

@Jakemoyo I did as you said, added a folder modules in scripts\addons, both in the installation folder C:\Users\{user}\DESKTOP\SOFTWARE\BLENDER\4_1\4.1 and in C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1, but I still get the same error message, even after restarting my machine.

Have you pasted a full script here that could be testable on people's personal machines? This kind of stuff is easier to test if we can debug on our end.

@Jakemoyo I edited my post to include the definition.py and dr.py modules.
